# Simple table in html

Tags: html

I manage to make number 1 to 5 but I'm confuse to how do i make number 6 on html, Can somebody help me with this. Please I'm new to programming and trying to learn.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoveflow - please remember this is not just a random general help forum: [edit] your post to follow the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask). And importantly, if you _need_ to post a picture, post a picture, and add that `!` in front of the link so it really does turn into an image.

Comment: The only difference between #6 and the rest is that in #6 you have other tables inside the table cells. Ignore 456 and 789, make the rest of the table, make two more tables (the 456 table and 789 table), and just put them inside the appropriate cell of the big table.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the OP doesn't have enough reputation to format picture

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables

Answer (score 0):

Like [Amadan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/240443/amadan) said in the comments of your post, you need to create a table inside of a table. This can be done just by inserting a `<table>` inside an already-existing `<table>` element. Utilizing the [`rowspan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-rowspan) and [`colspan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-rowspan) attributes, you can make code that creates #6's table with the following HTML code (CSS code solely for table visibility):

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td colspan="3">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td colspan="3">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2">7</td>
          <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>9</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```